# I don't want to update plugin if I don't have license key

Tags: wordpress

I want to prevent update as shown in screenshot if I don't have the correct authentication.

[image]

So how can I do that..?

Comment: But I want to show that notice. But whenever user updates without key then they will get error as shown in above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you don't want to show the updates since you don't have a license for it? It's a bit ignorant, since a lot of these updates container security fixes which you always should apply. But, you can use a plugin like:

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/hide-plugin-updates-notifications/

To hide specific notifications. You can also do it by code by adding this to your functions.php (modify the plugin path):

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
  unset( $value->response['akismet/akismet.php'] );
  return $value;
}

add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Niels van. But I want to show that notice. But whenever user updates without key then they will get error as shown in above screenshot.